Unable to Call StopDelay() Code from Custom Function
This simulation involves extruding bicycle frames from five extruders, storing them in a warehouse, then gathering them in one place for welding and assembly.
logic
whole logic
The five flows are identical.
Store1 to store5 is delay block.
store1 to store5
The transported agent is a 'ContainerBox', consisting of a boolean variable 'isStored' and a double variable 'num' representing the frame number.
Agent - ContainerBox
I set it up so that the variables are stored like this when the agent is stored in the rack. Also, I set agent.isStored = false; when the agent is in "RackPick".
Rack Store block
I want to call the stopDelay() function for store1 to store5 when the ContainerBox agent is "sink".(factory logic - sink6~sink15)
For the selectOutput block, I set it so that only the first agent goes to the 'true', and all subsequent agents go to the 'false'.
I wrote the following code to call the stopDelay() function for store1 to store5
function : request
ContainerBox box = randomWhere( containerBoxes, bx -> bx.isStored );
if (box != null  && box.num == 1 ){
    store1.stopDelay( box );
}
else if (box != null  && box.num == 2 ){
    store2.stopDelay( box );
}
else if (box != null  && box.num == 3 ){
    store3.stopDelay( box );
}
else if (box != null  && box.num == 4 ){
    store4.stopDelay( box );
}
else if (box != null  && box.num == 5 ){
    store5.stopDelay( box );
}

And in sink6 to sink15, I wrote request();
sink6 to sink15
However, when I run the simulation, there are no errors but the stopDelay() is not being called, and agents keep accumulating in store1 to store5. Could you help me identify any issues with my code or logic?
If you need any additional information, please ask me!
Thank you.

Always first build a tiny example model trying to replicate your core issue.
If you do that, you will see the stopDelay(box) works entirely fine.
However, you will also learn that the function is executed without any error if the box is not in the Delay block at all. So it is up to you to make sure it is actually in there before calling stopDelay()
Add a traceln and manually check this before calling the function. I bet they are not actually where you think they are, and your setup is wrong somewhere. Where? You need to find that out, put on your Sherlock hat :)

Oh.. I had set the population in the source block to the default population instead of the custom population! Thank you for giving me a chance to check again this!!
